# Are boosted trees always better than bagging trees?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, boosting, bagging

I've observed this on quite a few different types of datasets, `GBM` or `XGBOOST` always perform better than `Random Forests`. The accuracy jump on the test set is always more than 5%, for the datasets I've worked on.

Is it true that boosting is always a better option or it's just overfitting that I'm seeing, otherwise why would we choose `Random Forest`?

Note: I use `SMOTE` to balance out classes as I always get imbalanced data, not sure if this may be a factor

Comment: There is indeed a tendency that fine-tuned tree boosters are more accurate than random forests, at least for "neat" tabular data. However, in my experience, this is not the case when working with high dimensional data (too many covariables compared to the number of observations).

Such comparison of course requires a smooth validation and test strategy.